# Twitter API: Revoke Authorization

Tags: php, facebook

Can I use Twitter PHP API to deauthorize my app for a particular user, basically I like to have a toggle so the user can link or unlink their twitter account to my site, I have the link part working, now just need the unlink part.

Thanks

PS: I got this working for Facebook

Comment: Please shed some light on how you're connecting to Twitter. Does the app connect to your server first? You can't control anything on Twitter's servers even with your API key.

Comment: Using EpiOAuth & EpiTwitter to connect to Twitter, yes the app (website) is running on my server, so Iam making calls to get info from Twitter servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter does not allow this through their API.

Read more about this here: http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/64a49da760250d9/bfe896c156670692

You would have to have internal functionality which saves id of users which should not be displayed.

Comment: Thanks, yes it seems like thats the case, this is what I had to do with Youtube (google auth), but I was hoping for better solution for Twitter, as I found for Facebook (https://api.facebook.com/method/auth.revokeAuthorization?access_token=)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following POST request `https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/invalidate_token` to allow a registered application to revoke an issued OAuth 2 Bearer Token by presenting its client credentials. Once a Bearer Token has been invalidated, new creation attempts will yield a different Bearer Token and usage of the invalidated token will no longer be allowed.

It does not revoke the application in the users Apps section (under snettings) but it does have the same effect as re-authenticating the application.

https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth2/invalidate/token